# Change comma separated values to line break

Tags: php, magento, magento-2.3

Below phtml returns comma separated values from [‘code’]
How could I change the comma to a line break?

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <tr>

        <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ 
        $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `str_replace(',', '<br>', $_data['code'])`?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I have tried that but the page no longer opens. Maybe I am placing it in the wrong spot?

Comment: I don't know what `$_helper->productAttribute()` does.

Comment: Your question should show what you tried. I'm suggesting that you simple replace `$_data['code']` with that expression.

Comment: Below is what I have tried $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], str_replace(',', '<br/>', $_data['code']))

Comment: That's what I was suggesting, so I don't know why that would cause your page not to open. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php for how to enable full error reporting.

Comment: Page is loading ok now but does not change any of the data. Its got me stumped!

Comment: It looks like you're using some kind of framework or library. If you tag the question properly, it might attract people familiar with it.